# Maximum alternating sum in a number

Tags: python

Alternating sum is defined like this : 
[image: alternating sum]

I'm supposed to write a function which finds the maximum alternating sum with a specific length:
for example the number 43805 has alternating sums with length 3:

```
4-3+8,
3-8+0,
8-0+5
```

An example of the function output:`>>> altsum_digits(5**36, 12)
 18`

I wrote my code but for some reason I don't get the exact result, for the number 5**36 I get the answer 20 instead of 18, Can you please tell me what should I fix in my code?

Another question: let's define nplus, nminus, nmult as the number of adds, Subtractions and multiplication the function does each run, I'm supposed to write a Mathematical expression for each one the parameters  according to the inputs n and d, I'm a beginner and I have no clue how to do this, I would really appreciate any help.

Here is my code:

```
def altsum_digits(n,d):
    c = [int(l) for l in str(n)]

    maxaltsum=0
    tmpmax=0
    for i in range(0,d):
       tmpmax=tmpmax+((-1)**(i)*c[i])


    it=(len(c)-d)
    for i in range(1,it):
        tmpmax=c[i+d-1]-(tmpmax-c[i-1])
        if (tmpmax)>maxaltsum:
            maxaltsum=tmpmax
    print(maxaltsum)
```

Comment: You have two bugs I can see, one where you forget to initialize `maxaltsum` with the initial `tmpmax` and one where your second loop does one iteration too few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on simple debugging, I think your calculation of tmpmax based on previous tmpmax is incorrect, you missed a minus sign:
use `tmpmax=-c[i+d-1]-(tmpmax-c[i-1])` instead of `tmpmax=c[i+d-1]-(tmpmax-c[i-1])`.
Just think it through, it is logical. It is always very easy to get lost in the forest of alternating signs.

Comment: And both of @user2357112's comments are valid: your second loop needs an additional iteration, and maxaltsum should not be initialized to 0, but to the first tmpmax instead, just think about for example the parameters (123456, 2).

Comment: I changed the sign to minus as elias mentioned, and I got 18 for the first input but when I enter  (123456, 2) I get zero, why is that?

Comment: Because you initialize maxaltsum to 0. You should initialize it after your first loop, to the value of tmpmax.

Answer (score 0):

Of the three bugs mentioned in elias' answer and the comments (wrong initialisation of `maxaltsum`, wrong number of iterations in the second loop, and missing a `-` in the tmpmax calculation in the second loop), you can avoid ever running into at least the first one by using Python's builtins.

Whenever you have a problem that is "work out the maximum *something*", and your way of doing it involves exhaustively searching all the possible somethings for the maximum, you can use Python's builtin function `max`. Here's how you would do it here using a Python generator:

```
def altsums(n, d):
    c = [int(l) for l in str(n)] 

    alt = 0
    for i in range(0,d):
       alt=alt+((-1)**(i)*c[i])

    yield alt

    it=(len(c)-d)
    for i in range(1,it):
        alt = -c[i+d-1]-(alt-c[i-1])
        yield alt

print(max(altsums(5**36, 12))
```